# Rename music files so they alphabetically follow a playlist

Tags: bash, music, mp3, playlists

I have a bunch of mp3s I've organised into a playlist for a party. What I'd like to be able to do is easily rename these files so that they start with the position in the playlist:

```
001.Track.mp3
002.Track.mp3
.
.
.
```

Then they can simply be played in alphabetical order. Is this possible without just doing it manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:
I'm not sure if it needs something more but this should work.

```
    cat playlist.m3u | I=1 while read file; do
        mv $file $I.$file.mp3;
        I=$I + 1;
    done;
```

Edit: You could need I=`expr $I + 1'; instead of I=$I + 1;

Comment: maybe check first if $file exist

Comment: Yes you're right, if you have to use it more often this should be done.

Comment: Of course! How nice and simple. Should have occurred to me! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a file `my_playlist.txt` that contains the tracks in the order you want to play them, e.g.,

```
dancing all night long.mp3
charles trenet - je t'aime mon amour.mp3
mon petit poney - bo.mp3
charlie parker - donna lee.flac
```

and assuming that this file is in the same directory you have your music files. If this is not the case, please specify your question accordingly.

Then (observe good [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) practice that will work with file names that have spaces in them):

```
#!/bin/bash

pl=my_playlist.txt

# need number of files, to know the number of leading zeros
n=$(wc -l < "$pl")
lz=0
while ((n)); do ((++lz)); ((n/=10)); done

i=1
while read f; do
    [[ -z $f ]] && continue
    if [[ ! -f $f ]]; then
        printf "*** Error, file \`%s' not found.\n" "$f"
        continue
    fi
    printf -v target "%0*d.%s" "$lz" "$i" "$f"
    echo mv -vn -- "$f" "$target"
    ((++i))
done < "$pl"
```

If you run it as is, the renames will no occur, because of the `echo` in front of `mv`. This is just a little test. When you're happy with it, remove the `echo` and the rename will take place. The `mv` command has the two flags `-v` and `-n`:

- `-v`: be verbose (I like to know what's happening)
- `-n`: no clobber, so as to not overwrite otherwise existing files (safer)

*Note about the `printf` command*. It looks a little bit ugly, but there's nothing to be scared about. The part `%0*d` will take the two arguments `$lz` and `$i` and will be replaced by the number `$i` with `$lz` leading zeros. Then the `%s` will be replaced by the third argument, which is the file name. All this will be put in the variable `target`, thanks to the `-v` option. So that `target` will be something like:

```
0001.title of the file.mp3
```

Adapt and extend to your needs!

---

Now let's assume you've been playing with that, and you want to *undo* the renaming...
there are two possibilities:

1. You only have files of the form `XXXX.YYYY` where `XXXX` are digits, and you'd like to remove the digits and the period from the name:

   ```
   shopt -s extglob
   for i in +([[:digit:]]).*; do
       target=${i#*.}
       echo mv -nv -- "$i" "$target"
   done
   ```

   and remove the `echo` when you're happy.
2. You only want to do it for the files in your playlist `my_playlist.txt`:

   ```
   shopt -s extglob
   while read f; do
       a=( +([[:digit:]])."$f" )
       if ((${#a[@]}==0)); then
           printf "*** Error: can't find a match for file \`%s'\n" "$f"
       elif ((${#a[@]}>1)); then
           printf "*** Error: found several matches for file \`%s':\n" "$f"
           printf "    %s\n" "${a[@]}"
       else
           target=${a[0]#*.}
           echo mv -nv -- "$f" "$target"
       fi
   done < my_playlist.txt
   ```

   and as usual, remove `echo` when you're happy.

Answer (score 1):

I use Dolphin, a replacement for Nautilus and all I need to do is select the files I would like to rename, right click on the selection and...

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: I'm assuming that this is going to name the files in the order they're already in though? I want to rename in an order from a playlist.

Comment: Ah, that's a different matter. I'll take a look :)